# Can't debug JScript anymore because of an attached debugger (which is not attached!)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, jscript, wsh

Context: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, 64bit processor, VS2010

Using the [//X technique for script debugging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308364), and debugging JScript, I'm getting

> Unable to attach to the crashing process. A debugger is already attached.

However, I've just logged in, there's no crashing process as such (unless that's what //X does to connect to the debugger) and there's no debugger already attached. And yesterday this was working fine.

I've tried [detaching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317704/JScript-Debugger-Unable-to-attach-the-process-Anot) but in fact, there is no such option to detach is given after I click on the OK button in the above dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of problem generally occurs in IE 10 browsers. There could be a possible up-gradation of browser recently happened in your system. Please confirm your browser type & version.

http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.in/2013/04/unable-to-attach-to-crashing-process.html